# interface declaration

Tags: function, dll, interface

I have a DLL (ImageHelp) with a function GetImage. I want to use this function in different classes so I defined an interface IImages.
The function in the Interface, which has access to the DLL, is declared as 
Image GetImage();
In the classes I tried:

```
Image image = IImages.GetImage();
```

or

```
Image image = _imagehelp.GetImage();
```

In both cases I get errors. `classxyz does not implement GetImage.`

Any advice will be appreciated.

togo

Comment: What language?  Can you show the type definitions for `Image` and `IImages`?  (We probably don't need any of the method contents, just the member signatures.)  It's not entirely clear how this is all set up across the different assemblies.  Can you indicate in the type definitions which ones are in which assemblies?

Comment: For one thing, if `IImages` is an interface then `IImages.GetImage()` makes no sense.  An interface type is by definition not an implementation, so it shouldn't have a static method on it.  For the second code sample, what is `_imagehelp`?  For the error, what is `classxyz`?

Answer (score 0):

Your classes that use GetImage need to inherit IImages (classxyz for instance needs to inherit IImages).